# How to avoid “Please Verify you are a Human” with Headless Chrome Node.js API?

Tags: web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, puppeteer, botdetect

I am trying to use Puppeteer api to generate some pdf images from web sites but Perimeterx bot detection detects it as a bot and blocking site. Is it easy work around for it using Puppeteer to mimic real browser headers and by pass bot defender?

```
            var options = new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = true
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Downloading chromium");
        await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultRevision);

        Console.WriteLine("Navigating");
        using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options))
        using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
        {
            await page.GoToAsync("https://www.matchesfashion.com");

            Console.WriteLine("Generating PDF");
            await page.PdfAsync(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "image.pdf"));

            Console.WriteLine("Export completed");

            if (!args.Any(arg => arg == "auto-exit"))
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking how a bot can bypass bot-detection.

Comment: Related questions: [browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55364643/5627599), [browser fingerprinting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57737610/5627599)

Comment: @StephenCleary it's a valid question, you shouldn't be bringing your value judgements into this or assuming the user is doing something nefarious necessarily.  I'm actually researching bypass methods and your blocking of this question is hampering my research.  There's no point being opinionated.  We just need a neutral pro-knowledge forum.